# iOS: Crash when opening gamecenter achievements view

Tags: iphone, uiview, game-center

I'm coding a game for iphone in c++ and 100% opengl.
I need to add gamecenter to it so to show the UIViews I had to do something hackish.

```
void sb_socialShowAchievementsView(){
    SocialDelegate* del = [[[SocialDelegate alloc] init] autorelease];
    GKAchievementViewController *achievements = [[GKAchievementViewController alloc] init];
    if (achievements != nil) {
        achievements.achievementDelegate = del;
        HelperViewController* hvc = [[[HelperViewController alloc] init] autorelease];
        [globalGLView addSubview:hvc.view];
        [hvc presentModalViewController: achievements animated: YES];
    }
    [achievements release];
}
```

SocialDelegate implements protocols `GKAchievementViewControllerDelegate` and `GKLeaderboardViewControllerDelegate`.

`globalGLView` is my `EAGLView` instance.

and `HelperViewController` is just a `UIViewController` subclass.

The problem is when I call `sb_socialShowAchievementsView()` the app receives a SIGABRT with the following call stack and message:

```
*** Assertion failure in -[UIButtonLabel setTextColor:], /SourceCache/UIKit_Sim/UIKit-1262.60.3/UILabel.m:312
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Invalid parameter not satisfying: color'


#0  0x98ece156 in __kill
#1  0x98ece148 in kill$UNIX2003
#2  0x98f60899 in raise
#3  0x98f769b8 in abort
#4  0x961a2fda in __gnu_cxx::__verbose_terminate_handler
#5  0x03022333 in _objc_terminate
#6  0x961a117a in __cxxabiv1::__terminate
#7  0x961a11ba in std::terminate
#8  0x961a12b8 in __cxa_throw
#9  0x03022481 in objc_exception_throw
#10 0x02e8b238 in +[NSException raise:format:arguments:]
#11 0x022c6e37 in -[NSAssertionHandler handleFailureInMethod:object:file:lineNumber:description:]
#12 0x0052260f in -[UILabel setTextColor:]
#13 0x005ec3d3 in -[UIButton layoutSubviews]
#14 0x002a0481 in -[CALayer layoutSublayers]
#15 0x002a01b1 in CALayerLayoutIfNeeded
#16 0x004bd976 in __-[UINavigationController _positionNavigationBarHidden:edge:]_block_invoke_1
#17 0x0043698f in +[UIView(Animation) _performWithoutAnimation:]
#18 0x004c1e26 in -[UINavigationController _positionNavigationBarHidden:edge:]
#19 0x004bd9ae in -[UINavigationController _positionNavigationBarHidden:]
#20 0x004bc0c3 in -[UINavigationController _updateBarsForCurrentInterfaceOrientation]
#21 0x004b99b1 in -[UIViewController viewDidMoveToWindow:shouldAppearOrDisappear:]
#22 0x004c0bfd in -[UINavigationController viewDidMoveToWindow:shouldAppearOrDisappear:]
#23 0x0044217f in -[UIView(Internal) _didMoveFromWindow:toWindow:]
#24 0x00440d94 in -[UIView(Hierarchy) _postMovedFromSuperview:]
#25 0x00439c30 in -[UIView(Internal) _addSubview:positioned:relativeTo:]
#26 0x00437f83 in -[UIView(Hierarchy) addSubview:]
#27 0x0049355b in -[UITransitionView transition:fromView:toView:]
#28 0x006a3a16 in -[UIWindowController transition:fromViewController:toViewController:target:didEndSelector:]
#29 0x004b710d in -[UIViewController presentModalViewController:withTransition:]
#30 0x0007ee96 in sb_socialShowAchievementsView at social-bindings-iphone.mm:184
```

I just can't get what am I doing wrong...

Comment: could you do: [globalGLView presentModalViewController: achievements animated: YES];   ?

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the exact same problem. I have a class that manages all the game center stuff which I wrote a couple of months ago, and it worked fine. I tried to import it to a new project, and called the standard methods to present the `GKAchievementViewController`, then it crashed with the same SIGABRT as you had. Then I tried authenticating the player first (which I would normally do before calling the achievements controller), and the problem went away. I guess it's a bug in the `GameKit` framework. I couldn't file a bug report because bug reporter obviously has it's own bugs :)